# How to display a property from my array of objects in Angular /QuizApp

Tags: angular, interpolation, string-interpolation

I'm doing a Quiz Simulator App and i want after a button click "Show Answer" to show me the  answer of current Question. I'm a bit confused now, I've created a function which console.log all the correct answer from all the questions but i don't know how to Interpolate it in my app and how to do it for every current question.

btw. sry im newbie , my first post here

This is my component html:

```
`<div class="container p-5 ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-sm-8 offset-2">
      <p class = "text-center">{{currentQuestion + 1 }} of {{questions.length}} </p>
      <h3>{{questions[currentQuestion].question}}</h3>
      <div  *ngFor="let question of questions[currentQuestion].answers">
        <label appOptionBackground [correctAnswer]="question.correct"  class="form-check-label" for="answersRadio">
            <input  class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answersRadio" (change)="onAnswer(question.correct)" [disabled]="answerSelected">
          {{ question.option }}
        </label>

      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" (click)="showResult()">Show Result</button>
      <div *ngIf="result">
        Correct Answers: {{correctAnswers}} |  Incorrect Answers {{incorrectAnswers}}
      </div>
        <button (click) ="showAnswer()">show answer</button>

      <div>{{correctOption}}
      </div>
</div>`
```

This is my component ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QuestionsService } from '../shared/questions.service';
import {Question} from '../shared/question';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question-learn',
  templateUrl: './question-learn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question-learn.component.css']
})
export class QuestionLearnComponent implements OnInit {
questions: Question[] = [];

currentQuestion = 0;
answerSelected = false;
correctAnswers = 0;
incorrectAnswers = 0;

correctOption = '';

result = false;

constructor(private questionService: QuestionsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.questions = this.questionService.getQuestions();

  }



  onAnswer(option: boolean) {
    this.answerSelected = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.currentQuestion++;
      this.answerSelected = false;
    }, 2000);

    if(option) {
      this.correctAnswers++;
    } else {
      this.incorrectAnswers++;
    }

  }

  showResult() {
    this.result = true;
  }

  showAnswer() {
    for (let question of this.questions) {
        for (let answer of question.answers) {
          if (answer.correct === true ) {
              this.correctOption = answer.option;
             console.log(this.correctOption);
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is an image :**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncSP6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
  showAnswer = () => {
    const question = this.questions[this.currentQuestion];
    for (let answer of question.answers) {
      if (answer.correct === true ) {
        this.correctOption = answer.option;
        console.log(this.correctOption);
      }
    }
  }
```